# Unittest __unittest_skip__ access in beforeTest method

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I am using the skip decorator for a test:

```
@skip('I want this to skip')
def test_abc(self):
```

I also have a nose plugin to report test results with a defined

```
def beforeTest(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

the test case `test_abc` is getting captured by the `beforeTest` method. How can I check for the decorator value in my `beforeTest` method?

I see that the definition of unittest decorator has the following code:

```
test_item.__unittest_skip__ = True
test_item.__unittest_skip_why__ = reason
```

But I dont know how to access it from `beforeTest`. 
When running `args[0].test` has the test case object but I can seem to find where `__unittest_skip__` is defined

Thanks!

Comment: The actual question you are asking is a bit unclear. Consider revising your post.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code, there doesn't seem to be a *clean* way to do this.  `TestCase` seems to know what method it is testing based on the [`_testMethodName`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/unittest/case.py#l388) implementation detail.  If you have a reference to the running test case (maybe `args[0].test`?  I'm not familiar with `nose`...) you *could* use that, or you could parse it out of the return value from [`TestCase.id()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/unittest/case.py#l471).  Assuming you aren't doing something really funky, it would be something like:

```
test_name = test_case.id().rsplit('.', 1)[-1]
test_method = getattr(test_case, test_name)
if getattr(test_method, '__unittest_skip__', False):
    # Method skipped.  Don't do normal stuff.
```

Comment: Perfect! It does work, the reference to the running test case comes from `args[0].test` in the `beforeTest`. Thank you very much for the quick response!